# How to trigger ir.ui.view action to a Menu in Odoo

Tags: odoo, menuitem, odoo-15

This is my first Module I'm creating, I have learnt in the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/backend.html#data-files) that after creating the action (record tag) I have to mention this action in the (Menu tag) to act on it, as the following

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_list_ideas">
    <field name="name">Ideas</field>
    <field name="res_model">idea.idea</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field> </record> 
<menuitem id="menu_ideas" parent="menu_root" name="Ideas" sequence="10"
          action="action_list_ideas"/>
```

**My question is**

I want to create another action type

`record model="ir.ui.view"`
how to make the relation between the action and the menu ?

This is what I wrote, 4 actions for 2 menu

```
<!-- record ir.ui.view for menu "about company" --->
<record id="globalhaatahmedviewa" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">haatglobal_ahmed</field>
    <field name="model">haatglobal_ahmed.haatglobal_ahmed</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="16"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <!-- view content: <form>, <tree>, <graph>, ... -->
<form create="false" edit="false">
    HTML Text to 
</form>
    </field>
</record>

<!-- record ir.ui.view for menu "support" --->
<record id="globalhaatahmedviews" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">haatglobal_ahmed</field>
    <field name="model">haatglobal_ahmed.haatglobal_ahmed</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="16"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <!-- view content: <form>, <tree>, <graph>, ... -->
<form create="false" edit="false">
    HTML Text to 
</form>    </field>
</record>

<!-- record ir.window for menu "about company" --->
<record id="haatglobal_ahmed_about_a" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">HAAT_Global</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">haatglobal_ahmed.haatglobal_ahmed</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="globalhaatahmedviewa"/>
            <field name="help" type="html">
            <p> about company window </p>
            </field>
        </record>

<!-- record ir.window for menu "about company" --->
<record id="haatglobal_ahmed_about_s" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">HAAT_Global</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">haatglobal_ahmed.haatglobal_ahmed</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="globalhaatahmedviews"/>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p>
                    Support window
                </p>
            </field>
        </record>

<menuitem name="HAAT Global" id="haatglobal_ahmed.menu_root"/>
<menuitem name="About Company" id="haatglobal_ahmed.menu_a" parent="haatglobal_ahmed.menu_root" action="haatglobal_ahmed_about_about"/>
<menuitem name="Support" id="haatglobal_ahmed.menu_s" parent="haatglobal_ahmed.menu_root"
 action="haatglobal_ahmed_about_about" />
```

was that right?

My target is to create (main menu) and (two sub menu) if I click on the (sub menu) it will show just text in the page.

Thanks for help in advance

I'm odoo 15

Comment: You can specify the view in the window action using the [view_id](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/developer/reference/backend/actions.html#window-actions-ir-actions-act-window) field

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this line to your action record:

```
<field name="view_id" ref="you_action_id"/>
```

your action record will be like:

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_list_ideas">
    <field name="name">Ideas</field>
    <field name="res_model">idea.idea</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="globalhaatahmedview"/>
</record>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated the post and I wrote the whole code which I have wrote..... was that right ? because I'm still facing error

Answer (score 0):

The XML file does not fit the required schema!

Arch fields and the first help field will raise the following errors:

```
text not allowed here
element "field" incomplete
```

Odoo will expect a view type inside the arch field: form, tree, ...

You can wrap the text inside a `form` tag, for example:

```
<form create="false" edit="false">
    HTML Text to 
</form>
```

Form views are composed of regular HTML, this is why the above example should work but they are used to display the data from a single record.

The same thing to the window action, try to wrap the text inside a `p` tag

Odoo will use the [import_xml](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/import_xml.rng) RNG file and the corresponding views validation schemes in the [base](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/15.0/odoo/addons/base/rng) module to validate the structure and content of an XML document (data files). Check the [views](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/views.html) documentation for more details on what you can define inside a view arch.

Note that it's possible to define a new [view type](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/frontend/javascript_cheatsheet.html#creating-a-new-view-from-scratch) and display custom content using a [qweb](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/frontend/qweb.html) template

Comment: Thanks for your trying to help, I edited the post to include your suggestion, I run out that, the result was as error 
`odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /odoo54/custom/addons/haatglobal_ahmed/views/views.xml:96, somewhere inside
<menuitem name="About Company" id="haatglobal_ahmed.menu_a" parent="haatglobal_ahmed.menu_root" action="haatglobal_ahmed_about_about"/>`

Comment: Actually what i need is Main menu with html text only.

Comment: Your actions are `haatglobal_ahmed_about_s` and `haatglobal_ahmed_about_s` but you used `haatglobal_ahmed_about_about` in menu items. Make sure to define that action first.